# Uploading images using asp.net generic (testUpload.ashx Page) handler cross orgin access error throwing in jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

In jQuery Ajax, calling other host asp.net generic handler to upload images and I'm using jquery cross domian access "$.support.cors=true" but it's not working. Please help me to solve this issue.

SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for http://192.172.1.001/uploader/TestUploader.ashx?userId=1&fileName=Rose.png required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

[image]

```
function UploadUserImage(fileToUpload){
jQuery.support.cors = true;
    jQuery.ajaxFileUpload({
        type: "POST",
        //crossDomain: true,
        url: uploaderPath + '?userId=' + userID + '&fileName=' + fileName,
        fileElementId: fileToUpload,
        success: function (data, status) {
            if (status == "success" ) {
                jQuery("#lblUploadError").html("");
                UploadECOADetails(data.d);
            }
            else {
                jQuery("#lblUploadError").removeClass("blue");
                jQuery("#lblUploadError").addClass("red");
                jQuery("#lblUploadError").html(languageResource.resMsg_Error + data.documentElement.innerText);
                jQuery("#divUploadProgress").hide();
            }
        },
        error: function (data, status, e) {
            jQuery("#lblUploadError").removeClass("blue");
            jQuery("#lblUploadError").addClass("red");
            jQuery("#lblUploadError").html(languageResource.resMsg_Error + languageResource.resMsg_FailedToUploadEcoaInfo + e.message);
            jQuery("#divUploadProgress").hide();
            if (navigator.userAgent.search("MSIE") > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))  // If Internet Explorer, return version number
            {
                var control = jQuery("#" + fileToUpload);
                control.replaceWith(control = control.clone(true));
            }
            else {
                jQuery("#" + fileToUpload).val('');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please post your errors as text and not as code.

Comment: I meant as an edit, not in comments.

Comment: Thank you, i updated now